# Page transition library similar to Flutter Hero for Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, css-animations

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hero-transition
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hero

The Hero animation packages I found are the two listed above.
But I think this library is a little lacking in recognition.
Is there a package with the appropriate number of star or npm downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about Flutter Hero since this one is highly specific but you do have several ones that may be flexible and powerful enough to do anything with it:

- [vue-starport](https://github.com/antfu/vue-starport), using FLIP for the animations
- [GSAP](https://greensock.com/)
- [motion.dev](https://motion.dev/)

Otherwise, here is a good list of all the related libraries: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#animation
You could probably find something quite simple to use there, filling your exact needs.